# How to add a button on the left side of android app toolbar?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-styles

I want to add an **add-button on the left side of my android app toolbar

Comment: here --> https://en.proft.me/2016/07/22/how-create-actionbartoolbar-and-menu-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `YourActivity.java` use this,

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.Toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("ORDERS");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_NAME);
```

Use this outside of `onCreate` to set `Click Listener` to this Button

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
           

            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

In `activity_youractivity.xml` layout use this,

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/AppbarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/Toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

In `styles.xml` use this,

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</resources>
```

In `build.gradle (app)` use this,

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Comment: can I ask how to have a OnClickListener on this button? thanks...

Comment: @qiantext Doesn't that work on its own? Automatically going back?

Comment: no,actually I already have a toolbox so I only add  ( setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_NAME);) on my code, maybe because of this?

Comment: and I want to make an intent to move to another Activity after I click this button ,could you teach me what to do?

Comment: @qiantext Updated Answer...

Comment: @qiantext Upvote(Mark as Useful) the comments that helped you. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `setNavigationIcon` method in `Toolbar`:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom toolbox and design it anyhow that suits your need.

You can them replace the toolbar with the custom layout you just made.